# trouble adapting rubberduck VBA grammar to python (working in java) (antlr4 runtime)

Tags: parsing, antlr, grammar, antlr4, rubberduck

I'm actually trying to adapt the rubberduck grammar listed [here](https://github.com/rubberduck-vba/Rubberduck/tree/next/Rubberduck.Parsing/Grammar) for python parsing. For this, i have changed semantic predicates within the grammar :

- at line 297 and 298 from `{_input.Lt(1).Text.Equals("A")}?` to `{self.input.LT(1).getText().__eq__("A")}?`
- at line 571 from `{_input.La(-1) == NEWLINE}?` to `{self.input.LA(-1) == NEWLINE}?`

i then compile the grammar using standard commands given by official doc : `antlr4 -Dlanguage=Python2 VBALexer.g4 && antlr4 -Dlanguage=Python2 VBAParser.g4`

the result of this grammar parsing is the following :

```
warning(180): VBALexer.g4:300:15: chars '<INVALID>'..'/' used multiple times in set [[\]()\r\n\t.,'"|!@#$%^&*\-+:=; 0-9-/\\]
warning(180): VBALexer.g4:302:18: chars '\uFFFD' used multiple times in set [a-zA-Z_������]
warning(180): VBALexer.g4:302:18: chars '\uFFFD' used multiple times in set [a-zA-Z_������]
warning(180): VBALexer.g4:302:18: chars '\uFFFD' used multiple times in set [a-zA-Z_������]
warning(180): VBALexer.g4:302:18: chars '\uFFFD' used multiple times in set [a-zA-Z_������]
warning(180): VBALexer.g4:302:18: chars '\uFFFD' used multiple times in set [a-zA-Z_������]
warning(180): VBALexer.g4:304:25: chars '\uFFFD' used multiple times in set [a-zA-Z0-9_������]
warning(180): VBALexer.g4:304:25: chars '\uFFFD' used multiple times in set [a-zA-Z0-9_������]
warning(180): VBALexer.g4:304:25: chars '\uFFFD' used multiple times in set [a-zA-Z0-9_������]
warning(180): VBALexer.g4:304:25: chars '\uFFFD' used multiple times in set [a-zA-Z0-9_������]
warning(180): VBALexer.g4:304:25: chars '\uFFFD' used multiple times in set [a-zA-Z0-9_������]

warning(154): VBAParser.g4:626:0: rule lExpression contains an optional block with at least one alternative that can match an empty string
warning(154): VBAParser.g4:626:0: rule lExpression contains an optional block with at least one alternative that can match an empty string
warning(154): VBAParser.g4:646:0: rule argumentList contains an optional block with at least one alternative that can match an empty string
warning(154): VBAParser.g4:646:0: rule argumentList contains an optional block with at least one alternative that can match an empty string
```

I then try to parse the following simple VBA code :

```
Public Sub Module()
    X = 0
    Y = 1
    Z = 2
    Test1 = X + Y * Z
    Test2 = X - Y * Z
    Test3 = Z + X * Y - Y * Z
    Test4 = Z + X * Y Mod Z * 2 + 5 * Z
    Test5 = Z + X ^ 3 * Y Mod Z * 2 + 5 * Z ^ X
    Print #1, Test2 ; " is not a Boolean value" 
End Sub
```

using standard python code :

```
import antlr4
from VBALexer import VBALexer
from VBAParser import VBAParser

input = antlr4.InputStream(data)
lexer = VBALexer(input)
tokens = antlr4.CommonTokenStream(lexer)
parser = VBAParser(tokens)
tree = parser.startRule()
```

which gives me the following :

```
line 1:0 extraneous input 'Public' expecting {<EOF>, ':', <INVALID>, <INVALID>, <INVALID>, <INVALID>, ''', WS, LINE_CONTINUATION}
line 1:6 mismatched input ' ' expecting {<INVALID>, <INVALID>, <INVALID>}
```

if i print the tree i get the following :

```
(startRule (module Public moduleAttributes   Sub   Module ( ) \n         X   =   0 \n         Y   =   1 \n         Z   =   2 \n         Test1   =   X   +   Y   *   Z \n         Test2   =   X   -   Y   *   Z \n         Test3   =   Z   +   X   *   Y   -   Y   *   Z \n         Test4   =   Z   +   X   *   Y   Mod   Z   *   2   +   5   *   Z \n         Test5   =   Z   +   X   ^   3   *   Y   Mod   Z   *   2   +   5   *   Z   ^   X \n         Print   # 1 ,   Test2   ;   " is not a Boolean value"   \n End Sub \n) <EOF>)
```

However, if i adapt the grammar to java using the following :

- at line 297 and 298 from `{_input.Lt(1).Text.Equals("A")}?` to `{_input.LT(1).getText().equals("A")}?`
- at line 571 from `{_input.La(-1) == NEWLINE}?` to `{_input.LA(-1) == NEWLINE}?`

and then run the grammar parsing (exact same warning obtained) and compile the code using javac, i can correctly run `grun` on the sample :

```
grun VBA startRule -tree
Public Sub Module()
    X = 0
    Y = 1
    Z = 2
    Test1 = X + Y * Z
    Test2 = X - Y * Z
    Test3 = Z + X * Y - Y * Z
    Test4 = Z + X * Y Mod Z * 2 + 5 * Z
    Test5 = Z + X ^ 3 * Y Mod Z * 2 + 5 * Z ^ X
    Print #1, Test2 ; " is not a Boolean value" 
End Sub
(startRule (module moduleAttributes moduleAttributes moduleAttributes moduleDeclarations moduleAttributes (moduleBody (moduleBodyElement (subStmt (visibility Public) (whiteSpace  ) Sub (whiteSpace  ) (subroutineName (identifier (untypedIdentifier (identifierValue Module)))) (argList ( )) (endOfStatement (endOfLine \n (whiteSpace        ))) (block (blockStmt (mainBlockStmt (letStmt (lExpression (identifier (untypedIdentifier (identifierValue X)))) (whiteSpace  ) = (whiteSpace  ) (expression (literalExpression (numberLiteral 0)))))) (endOfStatement (endOfLine \n (whiteSpace        ))) (blockStmt (mainBlockStmt (letStmt (lExpression (identifier (untypedIdentifier (identifierValue Y)))) (whiteSpace  ) = (whiteSpace  ) (expression (literalExpression (numberLiteral 1)))))) (endOfStatement (endOfLine \n (whiteSpace        ))) (blockStmt (mainBlockStmt (letStmt (lExpression (identifier (untypedIdentifier (identifierValue Z)))) (whiteSpace  ) = (whiteSpace  ) (expression (literalExpression (numberLiteral 2)))))) (endOfStatement (endOfLine \n (whiteSpace        ))) (blockStmt (mainBlockStmt (letStmt (lExpression (identifier (untypedIdentifier (identifierValue Test1)))) (whiteSpace  ) = (whiteSpace  ) (expression (expression (lExpression (identifier (untypedIdentifier (identifierValue X))))) (whiteSpace  ) + (whiteSpace  ) (expression (expression (lExpression (identifier (untypedIdentifier (identifierValue Y))))) (whiteSpace  ) * (whiteSpace  ) (expression (lExpression (identifier (untypedIdentifier (identifierValue Z)))))))))) (endOfStatement (endOfLine \n (whiteSpace        ))) (blockStmt (mainBlockStmt (letStmt (lExpression (identifier (untypedIdentifier (identifierValue Test2)))) (whiteSpace  ) = (whiteSpace  ) (expression (expression (lExpression (identifier (untypedIdentifier (identifierValue X))))) (whiteSpace  ) - (whiteSpace  ) (expression (expression (lExpression (identifier (untypedIdentifier (identifierValue Y))))) (whiteSpace  ) * (whiteSpace  ) (expression (lExpression (identifier (untypedIdentifier (identifierValue Z)))))))))) (endOfStatement (endOfLine \n (whiteSpace        ))) (blockStmt (mainBlockStmt (letStmt (lExpression (identifier (untypedIdentifier (identifierValue Test3)))) (whiteSpace  ) = (whiteSpace  ) (expression (expression (expression (lExpression (identifier (untypedIdentifier (identifierValue Z))))) (whiteSpace  ) + (whiteSpace  ) (expression (expression (lExpression (identifier (untypedIdentifier (identifierValue X))))) (whiteSpace  ) * (whiteSpace  ) (expression (lExpression (identifier (untypedIdentifier (identifierValue Y))))))) (whiteSpace  ) - (whiteSpace  ) (expression (expression (lExpression (identifier (untypedIdentifier (identifierValue Y))))) (whiteSpace  ) * (whiteSpace  ) (expression (lExpression (identifier (untypedIdentifier (identifierValue Z)))))))))) (endOfStatement (endOfLine \n (whiteSpace        ))) (blockStmt (mainBlockStmt (letStmt (lExpression (identifier (untypedIdentifier (identifierValue Test4)))) (whiteSpace  ) = (whiteSpace  ) (expression (expression (expression (lExpression (identifier (untypedIdentifier (identifierValue Z))))) (whiteSpace  ) + (whiteSpace  ) (expression (expression (expression (lExpression (identifier (untypedIdentifier (identifierValue X))))) (whiteSpace  ) * (whiteSpace  ) (expression (lExpression (identifier (untypedIdentifier (identifierValue Y)))))) (whiteSpace  ) Mod (whiteSpace  ) (expression (expression (lExpression (identifier (untypedIdentifier (identifierValue Z))))) (whiteSpace  ) * (whiteSpace  ) (expression (literalExpression (numberLiteral 2)))))) (whiteSpace  ) + (whiteSpace  ) (expression (expression (literalExpression (numberLiteral 5))) (whiteSpace  ) * (whiteSpace  ) (expression (lExpression (identifier (untypedIdentifier (identifierValue Z)))))))))) (endOfStatement (endOfLine \n (whiteSpace        ))) (blockStmt (mainBlockStmt (letStmt (lExpression (identifier (untypedIdentifier (identifierValue Test5)))) (whiteSpace  ) = (whiteSpace  ) (expression (expression (expression (lExpression (identifier (untypedIdentifier (identifierValue Z))))) (whiteSpace  ) + (whiteSpace  ) (expression (expression (expression (expression (lExpression (identifier (untypedIdentifier (identifierValue X))))) (whiteSpace  ) ^ (whiteSpace  ) (expression (literalExpression (numberLiteral 3)))) (whiteSpace  ) * (whiteSpace  ) (expression (lExpression (identifier (untypedIdentifier (identifierValue Y)))))) (whiteSpace  ) Mod (whiteSpace  ) (expression (expression (lExpression (identifier (untypedIdentifier (identifierValue Z))))) (whiteSpace  ) * (whiteSpace  ) (expression (literalExpression (numberLiteral 2)))))) (whiteSpace  ) + (whiteSpace  ) (expression (expression (literalExpression (numberLiteral 5))) (whiteSpace  ) * (whiteSpace  ) (expression (expression (lExpression (identifier (untypedIdentifier (identifierValue Z))))) (whiteSpace  ) ^ (whiteSpace  ) (expression (lExpression (identifier (untypedIdentifier (identifierValue X))))))))))) (endOfStatement (endOfLine \n (whiteSpace        ))) (blockStmt (mainBlockStmt (fileStmt (printStmt Print (whiteSpace  ) (markedFileNumber # (expression (literalExpression (numberLiteral 1)))) , (whiteSpace  ) (outputList (outputItem (outputClause (outputExpression (expression (lExpression (identifier (untypedIdentifier (identifierValue Test2)))))))) (whiteSpace  ) (outputItem (charPosition ;)) (whiteSpace  ) (outputItem (outputClause (outputExpression (expression (literalExpression " is not a Boolean value")))))))))) (endOfStatement (endOfLine (whiteSpace  ) \n))) End Sub)) (endOfStatement (endOfLine \n))) moduleAttributes) <EOF>)
```

Is this a simple typo error within my semantic predicates in python? Or might it be a potential antlr python runtime bug? 
thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: i'm using the latest 4.7 version for java complete package as well as python runtime. i'll try with your version

Comment: Cool! I'm very interested in knowing what we're going to have to do to our grammar to make it work with 4.7 =)

Comment: just tried with the 4.5 package as i can't get the 4.3 one. Getting the following : `line 1:0 mismatched input 'Public' expecting {<INVALID>, <INVALID>, <INVALID>}`. Seems like i'll need to dig it more in depth...

Comment: Hmm, looks lile we'll need some help from TheAntlrGuy to upgrade to 4.7... Anyway note that RD's parser uses more than just VBAParser.g4; you'll run into issues with precompiler directives: RD interprets them to determine what the "live" code is, and hides the "dead" tokens from the parser. Also much of the analytical stuff relies on a number of resolver passes that traverse the parse trees and identify declarations and their references - parsing is a challenge, resolving is quite another! Got a link to your GitHub so I can give it a star? =)

Comment: no public github for the moment :) . Actually i'm still in the phase where i try to find possible best already made things for my project. I'm actually working on something similar to ViperMonkey, and to be honest, i find the official vba.g4 grammar quite awful to make a correct parsing and why not further interpreting... What really bothers me however is the fact there is no problem with your grammar in java but there is in python :(. I will maybe make some kind of mix between your grammar and the official one. But i need more free time ;D